# how to work with an .so file without running it at the command line g++

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, g++, shared-libraries

I've created a .so file called car.so. I would like to test and work with this library in a test.cc code . In the command line i would like to compile: g++ test.cc -o test. I don't want to also link (include) the library car.so.

How to do that?

My test.cc code looks like this:

```
void* handle = dlopen("/home/v3/car.so", RTLD_LAZY);

  Car* (*create)();
  void (*destroy)(Car*);

  create = (Car* (*)())dlsym(handle, "create_object");
  destroy = (void (*)(Car*))dlsym(handle, "destroy_object");

  Car* carr = (Car*)create();
  carr->brake();
  destroy( carr );
```

I would also like to ask if it's possible to include 3 .so file in a single .so file.

edit:

I am working on Ubuntu/Linux

Comment: Have a look at dynamic linking. This is operating-system dependent, but I assume you use some kind of Linux. There, have a look at dlsym and related functions.

Comment: YES. I AM WORKING OB UUNTU. WHAT DO YOU MEAN BY OPERATING SYSTEM DEPENDENT? IS IT POSSIBLE OR NOT TO RUN WITH G++ A C FILE THAT CONTAINS A LIBRARY WITHOUT INCLUDING THE LIBRARY TO THE COMPILATION COMMAND?

Comment: Man, it's something wrong with your Caps Lock

Comment: Yes it is possible. Within your source code, you load the library and use dlsym etc to find symbols in it. I don't know the syntax by heart, but the man pages for dlsym and related functions should help you out.

Comment: Creating a new question for you additional question is the best way to get good answers to it, as it is completely separate question (at least for us)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in General you should include .h file of your .so library in your (application)/ test.cc then compile that test.cc file by linking that .so file & use generated binaray.

i think this link will realy help you..
http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html

Comment: if i use dlsym is it necesarry and use -ldl is it necesarry to link with -llibrary?

Comment: ya it is necessory because when your execuatable is going to run it should be know where .so will be..